# No further undo information

Tags: undo, undo-tree-mode

I'm getting the "no more undo" message all too often, even I made changes that should be there in the history. This is seriously breaking my workflow.

This is my .emacs

https://github.com/skrat/dots/blob/master/emacs/.emacs

Comment: As I peer into my crystal ball, I see that perhaps the O.P. has left `undo-tree-enable-undo-in-region` at its default setting of non-nil and that the O.P. has an active region.  If that sounds like a possibility, then try `(setq undo-tree-enable-undo-in-region nil)`.  That will also avoid the O.P. encountering a different long-standing bug:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/37399/2287  Another possibility is that the undo-limits are too low and the undo-tree history is being truncated as a result ... the limits should be raised ...: `undo-limit`, `undo-strong-limit`, `undo-outer-limit`

Comment: @lawlist feel free to post it as an answer, I niled `undo-tree-enable-undo-in-region` and now I'm waiting, I mean, working, time will show.

Comment: I don't have the `undo-tree-enable-undo-in-region` variable. Anyways, did you solve this? I'm getting the same behavior after 2 or 3 undo's.

Answer (score 3):

There are two (2) likely suspects:

**I**.  `undo-tree-enable-undo-in-region` is at its default non-nil setting and the O.P. has an active region; i.e., there are no more available undos in that active region.  In such a case, try:

```
(setq undo-tree-enable-undo-in-region nil)
```

The above-mentioned setting will also avoid the O.P. encountering a different long-standing bug:

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/37399/2287

**II**.  Another possibility is that the undo-limits are too low for the needs of the O.P. and the undo-tree history is being truncated as a result .... In such a case, the limits may be raised for the following variables (depending upon system hardware, etc.):  `undo-limit`, `undo-strong-limit`, and `undo-outer-limit`.