# Does undo-tree-mode allow to undo a specific change?

Tags: undo-tree-mode

I am using undo-tree-mode in spacemacs and it works fine to show the history of changes and to reset the buffer to a specific state.

But sometimes I'd like to undo a change or sequence of changes which are not the last.
So I can imagine a keybinding that allows to undo the currently highlighted change in the tree, or to even select a range in the tree that should be undone.

Technically this should be possible as long as the following changes still apply without conflicts (their diff can still be located).

Does this feature exist? I couldn't find it under the active keybindings (`?`).

Comment: The closest thing that I can think of would be undo/redo in region, which had an illusive bug (last time I checked).  I think Dr. Cubitt changed the default value of `undo-tree-enable-undo-in-region` to `nil` due to the bug.  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/37393/2287  I cited the bug reports in the answer of the linked thread.  I have not tinkered with this library in the past few years.